# Hiding first column in production environment

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI to generate excel sheet. I am able to generate the excel successfully in test environment but the problem is at the production environment. the first column is auto hidden. The following two images shows the correct one and the wrong one respectively.

[image]

[image: The data is adjusted wrongly]

Comment: Are you creating a new xls or updating a template xls

Comment: I am creating a new xlsx spreadsheet @GV

Comment: Are you using autosizecolumn and have different fonts available on dev and production environment? different OS for dev/prod?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer,

I removed the following line of code

```
 sheet1.autoSizeColumn(0);
```

And I replaced it with

```
sheet1.setColumnWidth(0, 4096);
```

That solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can set a column as hidden/unhidden using:

```
 sheet.setColumnHidden(int columnIndex, boolean hidden);
```

So I'd recommend always setting the first column to not be hidden. Seems weird how one environment would hide it, and the other wouldn't.

Javadoc for Method [`boolean isColumnHidden(int columnIndex)`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#isColumnHidden%28int%29)

Comment: But I am not hiding any columns in my program why it autohides the first column ?

Comment: I'm not sure why it autohides the first column, but have you tried explicitly setting the first column to not be hidden?

Comment: I set auto hide to false